# Can someone explain this line of code in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So i have this program, it finds lowercase letters and turns them to uppercase. It works but can someone just explain what the code after the else statement does.

```
raise :: String -> String
raise xs =
    [x | char <- xs
     , char `elem` (['a'..'z'] ++ ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0' .. '9'])
     , let x = if char `elem` ['A'..'Z'] ++ ['0' .. '9'] 
               then char
               else ['A'..'Z'] !! head [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] ['a'..'z']
                                          , x == char]]
```

Comment: Looks like a ridiculously overcomplicated way of converting to uppercase. `Data.Char` has ready made conversion functions for this!

Comment: @RobinZigmond Insanely complex indeed. Even without the library, one could have used `toEnum (theRightOffset + fromEnum char)`. Even if we wanted to use `zip` at all costs, we could have `head [ up | (lo,up) <- zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z'] , lo == char ]` without using an index `i`. Further, `(lo,up) <- zip ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z']  ++ (char,char)` would make the `if elem ...` redundant. I'd guess that the OP contrived code was crafted in another (imperative?) language, and then translated preserving the code structure.

Comment: Possibly, but surely every imperative language has standard library functions for case conversion as well?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you've inherited this code and are now maintaining it, do yourself and future users/maintainers a favor and replace this function with `import Data.Char` and `raise xs = [ toUpper x | x <- xs, isAscii x && isAlphaNum x ]`.  This is more readable and will perform much better.  (The `isAscii x` check can be dropped if the string is known to be ASCII or if you discover you actually want non-ASCII Unicode digits and letters to pass through the filter and get uppercased, too.  Check the docs for details.)

Answer (score 2):

you can try it yourself in ghci (type 'ghci' or 'stack ghci' from a command line, depending on how you've installed Haskell, or even use one of those 'try haskell online' services)!

```
> let f char = ['A'..'Z'] !! head [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] ['a'..'z'], x == char]
> f 'x'
'X'
> f '3'
{Prelude.head empty list error}
```

What does the part in the list do? Let's try it out!

```
> let f char = [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] ['a'..'z'], x == char]
> f 'b'
[2]
> f '3'
[]
```

See how you can use ghci to figure out what a function does?
Need help figuring out what arguments to add to f? Consider this:

```
> let f = [i | (i, x) <- zip [0..] ['a'..'z'], x == char]
{not in scope error: char}
```